# Create mosaic photo gallery - formulas

Tags: javascript

I want develop mosaic photo gallery. Elements should be place based on it's "weight" - the first horizontal element should be the widest, second two should be smaller etc. So i can't find out the formula to calculate element's weight. Also there are shouldn't be single elements in the row. So the second question is how to calculate the number of rows and the number of elements for the each row?